# Flexbox (flex-direction: column): wrapped child not positioned correctly when one child has fixed width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using a flexbox layout with `flex-flow: column wrap`. I am setting a height for the flexbox container. What I am trying to achieve is to have the first child element take the whole height so that the next children will wrap to the the next column. In my case, those children are wrapping to the next column, however there is a huge space between their column and the column of the first child. It seems as though the fact that I set the width of the first child somehow affects the positioning of the wrapped children.

Here is what I try to achieve:
[image: What I try to achieve]
Here is the problem I am having:
[image]

Here is link to a codepen: [codepen](https://codepen.io/yankolo/pen/EMXYYj?editors=1100)

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.child1 {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  max-width: 100px;
}

.child2 {
  flex: 1 0 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.child3 {
  flex: 1 0 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a Flexbox question, but I'd like to throw CSS Grid into the mix. It's designed to handle both `x`/`y` layout directions. While `flexbox` can sometimes handle the `y` part, it is usually with greater difficulty/hacks.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.child1 {
  background-color: green;
  grid-row: 1/-1; /* Begin at 1 and go to the end */
}

.child2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.child3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Agree with this. Flexbox isn't really designed to handle things that are different sizes/directions. You can see the samples on W3 schools to see how each can be used: [Grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) and [Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp).

Comment: @Nick Yah, I love Flexbox dearly, but found myself overusing it, since I knew it pretty well. The more I learn Grid, the more I realize there's a time and place for everything.

Comment: @AndyHoffman I have read that browser support is still lacking for grid. In addition, it seems that IE11 doesn't support grid well. What do you think? Should I use it or should I avoid it for now?

Comment: @yankolo Browser support (unprefixed) is [above 85%](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid). Using a pre-processor, you can still use Grid in IE/10+. Even Opera Mini understands Grid. I would recommend using it today.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set explicit width to your element. Acutally they are stretched by default.

If you remove the `max-width` you will have the following. Two eqaul columns where your element are stretched.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.child1 {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
}

.child2 {
  flex: 1 0 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.child3 {
  flex: 1 0 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child3"></div>
</div>
```

Adding `max-width` will simply restrict the width of the first element in its column

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.child1 {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  max-width:100px;
}

.child2 {
  flex: 1 0 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.child3 {
  flex: 1 0 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child3"></div>
</div>
```

And if you change the alignment you will get this:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  align-items:flex-start;
}

.child1 {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
}

.child2 {
  flex: 1 0 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.child3 {
  flex: 1 0 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child3"></div>
</div>
```

You will see nothing because we removed the stretch alignment and there is no width defined.

Add some width to have the needed result:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  align-items:flex-start;
}

.child1 {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  width:20%;
}

.child2 {
  flex: 1 0 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  width:80%;
}

.child3 {
  flex: 1 0 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  width:80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child3"></div>
</div>
```